Eighties movie featuring a destruction derby-scene, with a Darth Vader "doll" on roof of car (?)
Has anyone seen a movie featuring a scene with a destruction derby and a car with a life size
Darth Vader doll on the roof? I may be mistaken, but I am wondering if there's a scene with an airplane graveyard as well.

According to References to Star Wars in other movies, this if from the 1984 film Grandview, U.S.A.

One of the demolition derby cars is named "DARTH VADER" and has a full-size caped figure on the roof.

I can't find an image of the car for confirmation, but IMDb does list Star Wars in the Connections section for Grandview, U.S.A.
